# Laravel 5.1 doesn't take my Sender's email

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am currently using Laravel 5.1 and when trying to send an email with:

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', ['user' => $user_data, 'locale' => $locale], function ($m) use ($user_data, $subject) 
{
    $m->from('myemail@domain.com', 'My subject');
    $m->to($user_data['email'], $user_data['name'])->subject($subject);
});
```

Laravel is not taking the email that I am writing in the `$m->from()`call and is using the email I have in the email.php instead.

Is there any way you can help me with this?

Comment: which email service providers are you using?

Comment: I am using gmail if that's what you meant. But I don't know why it's not taking the email writing in the $m->from() call

Comment: most email service providers reject the `from` address that differs from your username, or you need to configure other different from address. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en